# Linking two lists to update when one or the other is changed

Tags: list, lookup-column, list-form

I am a bit of a SharePoint novice and I am having a few problems getting it to do what I would like it to do

I want to link two separate lists: for example if I check a check box for one of the item's columns it checks the same check box for the same item on the separate list.

I tried using Lookup to solve this problem but found that once I checked the box in the column on the one list it made the option available for all of the items on the list. I work for Student Services at the University of Southampton so each item on my many different lists refers to a particular student.

It's hard to explain so perhaps an example would help:

- On List1 I have a column called 'Student has attended workshop' this is a tick box
- On List2 I have the exact same column. I enter a new item (which would be a student and their details) for example I put Joe Jones onto both List1 and 2.
- List1 is the main list and he has attended his workshop so I tick this box
- I don't want to have to then go to List2 and tick the same box, I am hoping that there is a way for that List2 to understand that that particular tick box has been checked and automatically update it.

If any one has a solution or suggestion it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand properly, you need to sync the two given lists. If there are any changes done on list1 one it should be reflected to list2. I am not sure about any OOB(Out of the box) solution. But you can write a Event Receiver and in custom code you can update the changes in either of the list.

So you need to write Event Receivers for both of the lists.

For details about the Event Receivers please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem